# php modulo return wrong result

Tags: php

I got problem with this code:

```
if (!empty($_GET[ "lic" ])) $lic = $_GET[ "lic" ]; else $e = true;
echo ($lic % 11);
```

When I post `8911076856` it echoes `1`, but it should be `0`.

Comment: Might that be because `8911076856` is too high for an int, and overflowing?

Comment: I think that's not the problem as `var_dump(8911076856 % 11);` returns `int(0)`. Call `var_dump($lic)` before echoing the modulo.

Comment: @Florent - that is the problem. It's a 32bit system and he's trying to handle value too large to fit 4 byte integer. You probably tested on 64 bit system.

Comment: @Florent: In that operation, the number `8911076856` is parsed as a `float`, but cast internally to an `integer` for the modulus.  Try `var_dump((int)8911076856);` to see what it's actually using in the operation.

Comment: probably its 32b system, i dont know it exactly (Apache/2.2.15 (Debian) Server), but if it doesnt work, than is easy to find out

Comment: but is there any greater numeric variable than int that can be used in php? if yes how to declare that type of variable?

Comment: and theres another problem, when i insert this value (8911076856) into mysql db it wont save it, it save 2147483647 insted. I change mysql column type to bigint (and float as well), but with no success... how to save it ?(modulo now works with fmod function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [fmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php):

```
echo fmod(8911076856, 11);
```

Comment: +1.  Out of curiosity, is the benefit of `fmod()` over `(float)$x % (float)$y` just the precision of the result?

Comment: No, `(float)$x % (float)$y` does not give the correct result for values of $x above PHP_INT_MAX. E.g. `(float)8911076856 % (float)10` gives 4 instead of 6. Apparently the modulo operator casts both arguments back to int.

Answer (score 9):

The value "8911076856" is probably above the maximum integer value of your system.

```
echo ((int)8911076856);
```

My result is 321142264 on my 32 Bit system.

Comment: That's right, I got the right result (`0`) on a 64bits system

Comment: In this case, PHP automatically converts the number to a float. Apparently, the modulo operator does not work correctly on floats.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely being caused because the number you're posting is higher than `PHP_INT_MAX`, which is 9223372036854775807 on most 64-bit systems AFAIK.  If you're using a 32-bit system (which I expect you are), it's probably 2147483647.

Comment: On 32-bit machines, it is 2147483647.

Comment: @Sjoerd: You're right, my mistake.  I corrected my answer.  Forgot I was on my laptop. :-P

Answer (score -2):

Did you tried this:

if (!empty($_GET[ "lic" ])) $lic = **intval**($_GET[ "lic" ]); else $e = true;

echo ($lic % 11);

Comment: This won't work. Intval returns an int, and 8911076856 does not fit in an int. I.e. `intval(8911076856)` will give 321142264 on 32-bit machines.